# Reading schedules of employees from an excel sheet

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, import-from-excel

I'm uploading an excel sheet and reading its values to insert it into my database. Inside the excel sheet i have "ID" "Name" and log in and log out values for all the days of the months from 1 till 31.

PHP code:

```
function getSchedule($filepath,$con,$filename){

    require_once '';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath); 
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {



            $sql="INSERT INTO `schedule` (`Status`,`LastChange`, `Location`,'Date','ID','Name' ) VALUES (";
            for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
                $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                if($col==5){
                     $sql.="'$val'";
                }else{
                    $sql.="'$val', ";}
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got you right.

You can allow the value "null" on the days 29, 30, 31. Doing this you can do the same query as before.

For PHP you have to get the values anyway. And you get them out of your File, so this means, the 29th of February to 31th of February are "". Just let PHP replace "" with null and you are done on that job. :)

Comment: certain days maybe off days, and there will be in the schedule written "off"

Comment: Should be something like this: `if ($Value_96 === "") { $Value_96 = null; }`

Comment: this will specify a certain specific value, but what if a string is written in a random value

Comment: Yeah - thats true. You have to do it for the days. I'm at work so I can't calculate which Values are affected from that Day 28 to 31 issue. You have to do it for all those values. Or you specify your Time-Fields as a String, so "" is valid, too. :)